# Avoid DMARC blocks while using Envelope-Sender in PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

We use PHP on CentOS 6.4 to send emails for our business.

For reasons that I won't go into, emails go out FROM the user's email address (to ensure they get all replies and out of office responses) with our email address as SENDER (to get around SPF checks) and our ndr mailbox as ENVELOPE-SENDER (to catch bounce-backs). Using their email in the FORM address is something we do not want to change.

Following Yahoo.com & AOL.com's decision to increase their DMARC policy, using the ENVELOPE-SENDER now fails their checks (despite specifying a SENDER!). However, skipping this step means that we don't get any bounce backs and it is vital that we receive these.

Specifying RETURN-PATH in the mail headers doesn't work as is widely reported.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: For better googlability, an example of how it looks like in the mail logs: `to=<contact@x.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.196.27] said: 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if 550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 550-5.7.1  http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC 550 5.7.1 initiative.`
from=<contact@lw.x.com> - SMTP sender, From: some <some@yahoo,com> - envelope

Answer (score 4):

My company sends emails on behalf of our many customers, to other customers (to protect anonymity of the receiver until they choose to respond, at which point the emails should travel only between the 2 customers).

We were spoofing the 'From' address, until this recent restrictive change. So what I have done to fix it is:

**Set 'sender' and 'return-path' to 'mbox@mycompany.com'. This allows the receiving server to check that the sending mailbox exists and catches bounces.**

**Set 'reply-to' to 'customer1@something.com', the original sender's email.**

Out of thousands of emails in the 2 days since I implemented this, we have received 14 email responses mistakenly addressed to 'mbox@mycompany.com'. 5 turned out to be the sender hitting Reply All and we got CC'ed. 4 were due to the sender creating a new email and copying our email address instead of using Reply. Of the remainder, about half are sent from yahoo.com and aol.com, so I'm still working on why they aren't respecting the reply-to in a small percentage of cases.

So basically, my fix worked for all but 0.003% of emails. I'll reply to this answer if I can determine what causes the remainder of the failures.

Comment: What do you set From to? The same as Sender?

Comment: Yes, Sender, Return-Path and From would all be the same value, which is an email address on your mail server. Reply-To gets set to the sending customer's email address.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the case that envelope-sender and sender not matching is not causing your problem. Here is the part of the spec that appears to be relevant:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-kucherawy-dmarc-base/?include_text=1

> The domain name extracted from a message's RFC5322.From field is
>        the primary identifier in the DMARC mechanism.  This identifier is
>        used in conjunction with the results of the underlying
>        authentication technologies to evaluate results under DMARC.

If I am reading this correctly (and if email recipients are actually following spec), then it's basically up to Yahoo to reverse their decision, and there's little you can do except not use yahoo.com addresses as from addresses.